# AIX sftp to IBM sftp server using proxy fails

Tags: proxy, sftp, ibm-unix-system-services

We have support server where would need to upload the snap data to IBM  using proxy connection. We have already whitelisted the Server IP Address on the proxy side, Tried the ssh  -J proxyjump option getting connection closed error. 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host.

Server IP: 10.88.35.12

Proxy Server Details: 10.83.9.75
port: 8080

IBM SFTP Server Details: sftp.ecurep.ibm.com
Port: 22

Comment: Ask IBM. They own the system and you are paying.

Comment: Agree.. Already raised a support case. no response..

Comment: Some strace-like thing?

Comment: Can you ssh to the proxy?

Comment: Is this a HTTP proxy?  `-J` is for "middle" SSH servers ("jump hosts"), not for HTTP proxies

Comment: yes Stephen its an HTTP Proxy. But the firewall team told if we give the IP address and port it would allow the access

Comment: I can ssh the proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sftp using CURL package in AIX

## Command Sample:

curl –L –k –x ‘Proxy Server details: Port ‘  -v –l sftp server with path –user "anonymous: Your email ID " -T “File name"